# Expression Engine - if category_id not working?

Tags: php, html, expressionengine

I can't seem to get the if conditional statements for category id to work on a view (title_permalink) page.

My code is as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product"}
    <p><b>Product:</b> {product_item} &ndash; {categories}{if category_id == "8|9|10|11"}<b>Price (USD):</b>{/if}{if category_id == "not 8|9|10|11"}<b>Price (GBP):</b>{/if}{/categories} {product_price}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Surely this should work? So if i'm on category id 8 it will display "Price (USD)" and if i'm on category id 2 it should display "Price (USD)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. EE conditionals follow PHP's conditional syntax very closely.

Try this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product"}
    <p><b>Product:</b> {product_item} &ndash; {categories}
        {if category_id == "8" OR category_id == "9" OR category_id == "10" OR category_id == "11"}<b>Price (USD):</b>{if:else}<b>Price (GBP):</b>{/if}
    {/categories} {product_price}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi D-Rock, thanks but it is throwing me back an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/public_html/admin/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(650) : eval()'d code on line 77

Comment: Nevermind, sorry I had a tag open! Works a treat. Thank you! So is there no such conditional as {if category_id == "1|2|3|4"} ??

Comment: Correct - the conditionals in EE are (basically) directly converted to PHP conditionals, so all the syntax and rules of PHP conditionals apply.